# How to retrieve an element value from json using java?

Tags: java, json

Here is the json string from which i have to retrieve the element value

```
{ "search": { "entry": [
{ "d": "op=example.com",
"at": [
{ "name": "id", "value": [ "786786876" ] },
{ "name": "name", "value": [ "usaduas" ] }]
},
{ "d": "op=example.com",
"at": [
{ "name": "id", "value": [ "786876876" ] },
{ "name": "call", "value": [ "gyudyusg" ] }]
},
{ "d": "op=example.com",
"at": [
{ "name": "call", "value": [ "hsadkjhsakjdh" ] },
{ "name": "id", "value": [ "768768768" ] }]
}
```

I want to retrieve the text from attribute or node "name" : "call". I want to retrieve this value using jsonPath.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: which `json` library you used ? `simple.json` or `google.GSON` there are so many others too. ?? @Shashank

Comment: @VikrantKashyapRight now i am using com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath for it.

Comment: Have your tried this link > http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath

Comment: @VikrantKashyap  yes I looked into it but it didn't help much. In your first comment you mentioned other libraries also which can help me. Could you elaborate on those??

Comment: @RC. String exp = "$.search.entry.at[?(@.name = call)].value";
    JsonNode pincodes = JsonPath.read(exp, Jsonstring, JsonNode.class)

Right now i tried with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try one of these as per your understanding. These two are most convenient and highly used API to `Serialize` or `Deserialize` the `JSONObject` [google gson API tutorial-convert-java-object-to-from-json](http://howtodoinjava.com/best-practices/google-gson-tutorial-convert-java-object-to-from-json/)

OR 
 [Google Json simple API example-read-and-write-json](http://www.mkyong.com/java/json-simple-example-read-and-write-json/)